# Sencha saving to localstorage warning

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am getting a warning when saving data to local storage.Saving is working fine for me.but

store.sync()

generates the warning...

"[WARN][Ext.data.Batch#runOperation] Your identifier generation strategy for the model does not ensure unique id's. Please use the UUID strategy, or implement your own identifier strategy with the flag isUnique."

When i hunt for the solution i found it is the problem with the id of model..in my case i am directly giving the fields in the store.there is no model file for me.I tried with some of the solution.nothing worked for me .Hope you can understand.Pls help me

This is my code

```
Ext.define('MyAppp.store.MyStore', {
        extend:'Ext.data.Store',
        requires:['Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'],
        config: {
            remoteSort : true,
            identifier: {
                type: 'uuid'
            },
            fields:[
                {name:'firstname',type:'string'},    
                {name:'lastname',type:'string'},
                {name:'userID',type:'number'}
            ],
            proxy: {
                 type :'localstorage',
                 id:'LogInStore'
            }
        }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug before Version 2.0.1 of Sencha Touch.

See here:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185132-LocalStorage-proxy-using-id-that-is-not-an-integer-(32-digit-hex)

I had the same problem. Solution was:

```
identifier: {
                type: 'uuid'
            },
```

What you already have in your settings.